# How to calculate a series with complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I would like to calculate the following series, and I don't really know where to begin, or how to do it.

---

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(nj^n+1\right)}{n!}$

---

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{n^2j^n}{\left(2n\right)!}$

---

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{\left(kn\right)!}$ with k being from N*

I am not asking for complete solutions (It would be appreciated). I want a starting point or some ideas on how to do these kind of exercises.

j  is the imaginary unit ($j^2=−1$)

Comment: When you say "complex numbers", do you mean to say that $j$ is the imaginary unit ($j^2 = -1$)? Also, when people say "power series", this isn't usually what they refer to. It's possible one can use power series to solve this, but apart from that these are just series.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I rephrased the question. And yes, j is the imaginary unit.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What is $j$?

Comment: j is the imaginary unit ($j^2=−1$)

Comment: Hints: if you know the power series of $f(x)$, what are the power series of $f'(x)$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}f(xe^{2r\pi j/k})?$

Comment: Thanks for the hint metamorphy. I actually have to check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first series.Firstly you can easily prove that the series is convergent (by comparison). So you can decompose the series in a sum of two convergent series and add their respective limits.

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(nj^n+1\right)}{n!}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{nj^n}{n!}+\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{n!}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{nj^n}{n!}+e=j\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{(n+1)j^n}{(n+1)!}+e$$

The first series is the derivative of :
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{j^n}{n!}=e^j$$
So $$j\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{(n+1)j^n}{(n+1)!}=j(e^j)'=je^j$$

Finally :
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(nj^n+1\right)}{n!}=je^j+e$$

For the second series you can use the power series of $\sinh$ and $\cosh$.

For the third series you will probably need to use some kind of hypergeometric function